# find cheat engine pointers in ghidra

Tags: memory, assembly

I find a pointer of my health so a function would have made the pointer and put the health in it (tell me if I'm wrong) how do I look for the function?

Note,
as comments point out: health - I talk about a games health. So Health points. I want to find the function that handles this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. If you want to find a function that edits your player health (and possibly find a static address of for example player class) you can just simply right click the address of health you found, then click `Find out what writes to this address`. All addresses (in the middle of some function) that written to your health will be listed.

[image: Cheat Engine]

You can then copy the address that belongs to some function and inspect the function in for example Ghidra.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong about my understanding of what you want to achieve:
Find a specific memory address in a running application(I assume a game? becuase you're talking about health, so I guess health-points?)
If so, have you found the address already in cheat engine?
If yes, you can search for strings/values in both Cheat Engine and in Ghidra.

described in this article, [Ghidra code analysis](https://blogs.blackberry.com/en/2019/07/an-introduction-to-code-analysis-with-ghidra)

```
Investigate a String Reference
Figure 13: View string references
```